# Tensorboard: AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I'm getting this error when i use the tensorboard callback while training.

I tried looking for answers from posts related to tensorboard errors but this exact error was not found in any stackoverflow posts or github issues.

Please let know.

The following versions are installed in my pc:

Tensorflow and Tensorflow GPU : 2.0.0

Tensorboard: 2.0.0

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and fixed it with this hack

```
model._get_distribution_strategy = lambda: None
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug on tensorflow's side. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/34870

Remove tensorboard callback for now.

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly happens because of mixed imports from keras and tf.keras. Make sure that throughout the code exact referencing of libraries is maintained. For example instead of `model.add(Conv2d())` try `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D())` , applying this for all layers solved the problem for me.